# D3.js pie chart color scale

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, pie-chart

Considering a dataset like this:

```
var pie_data = [{
    "hard_skill": "Strategy",
    "course_area_percentage": 9
}, {
    "hard_skill": "Analytics",
    "course_area_percentage": 18
}, {
    "hard_skill": "Economics",
    "course_area_percentage": 11
}, {
    "hard_skill": "Finance",
    "course_area_percentage": 7
}, {
    "hard_skill": "HR",
    "course_area_percentage": 5
}, {
    "hard_skill": "Innovation",
    "course_area_percentage": 2
}, {
    "hard_skill": "International",
    "course_area_percentage": 5
}, {
    "hard_skill": "Marketing",
    "course_area_percentage": 7
}, {
    "hard_skill": "Operations",
    "course_area_percentage": 14
}, {
    "hard_skill": "Others",
    "course_area_percentage": 11
}, {
    "hard_skill": "Project",
    "course_area_percentage": 11
}]
```

I'm creating a pie chart in order to show all of these skills as slices of the chart. The idea then is to give a greener color (meaning it is more important), from a red to green color scale, to the skill that has higher percentage.

I've tried using `d3.scale.ordinal()` `and d3.scale.linear()` with different ranges and domains, but the colors do not match to the pattern described above. They seem to be inverted, like this:

[image]

My code for the color scale:

```
var pie_colorScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    //.domain([0,pie_data.length])
    //.range(["#d7191c", "#eef200", "#008e15"]);                    
    //.range(["#d7191c","#f19d00","#eef200","#3fe256", "#008e15"]);
    .range(["#008e15", "#3fe256", "#eef200", "#f19d00", "#d7191c"]);
```

Does the mapping of the colors to the values have to be manually set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your desired outcome...

> the idea then is to give a greener color (meaning it is more important), from a red to green color scale, to the skill that has higher percentage.

..., an ordinal scale is not the adequate choice.

You can use a linear scale with two colours in the range, "red" and "green", but the result is not nice. So, this solution uses three colours in the range: "red", "yellow" and "green".

The trick to do that is using three values in the domain:

```
var color = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([d3.min(pie_data, d => d.course_area_percentage),
        d3.mean(pie_data, d => d.course_area_percentage),
        d3.max(pie_data, d => d.course_area_percentage)
    ])
    .range(["red", "yellow", "green"]);
```

Here is a demo:

```js
var pie_data = [{
  "hard_skill": "Strategy",
  "course_area_percentage": 9
}, {
  "hard_skill": "Analytics",
  "course_area_percentage": 18
}, {
  "hard_skill": "Economics",
  "course_area_percentage": 11
}, {
  "hard_skill": "Finance",
  "course_area_percentage": 7
}, {
  "hard_skill": "HR",
  "course_area_percentage": 5
}, {
  "hard_skill": "Innovation",
  "course_area_percentage": 2
}, {
  "hard_skill": "International",
  "course_area_percentage": 5
}, {
  "hard_skill": "Marketing",
  "course_area_percentage": 7
}, {
  "hard_skill": "Operations",
  "course_area_percentage": 14
}, {
  "hard_skill": "Others",
  "course_area_percentage": 11
}, {
  "hard_skill": "Project",
  "course_area_percentage": 11
}]
var width = 500,
  height = 500,
  radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;


var color = d3.scale.linear()
 .domain([d3.min(pie_data, d=>d.course_area_percentage),
 d3.mean(pie_data, d=>d.course_area_percentage),
 d3.max(pie_data, d=>d.course_area_percentage)])
 .range(["red", "yellow", "green"]);

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
  .outerRadius(radius - 10)
  .innerRadius(0);

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
  .sort(null)
  .value(function(d) {
    return d.course_area_percentage;
  });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
  .data(pie(pie_data))
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "arc");

g.append("path")
  .attr("d", arc)
  .style("stroke", "gray")
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return color(d.data.course_area_percentage);
  });

g.append("text")
.attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
  })
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.data.hard_skill;
  });

function type(d) {
  d.population = +d.population;
  return d;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

As an alternative solution, if you want to use the color array you wrote in the question...

```
.range(["#008e15", "#3fe256", "#eef200", "#f19d00", "#d7191c"]);
```

... you should use a quantize (or quantile) scale instead:

```
var color = d3.scale.quantize()
    .domain(d3.extent(pie_data, d => d.course_area_percentage))
    .range(["#d7191c", "#f19d00", "#eef200", "#3fe256", "#008e15"]);
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var pie_data = [{
  "hard_skill": "Strategy",
  "course_area_percentage": 9
}, {
  "hard_skill": "Analytics",
  "course_area_percentage": 18
}, {
  "hard_skill": "Economics",
  "course_area_percentage": 11
}, {
  "hard_skill": "Finance",
  "course_area_percentage": 7
}, {
  "hard_skill": "HR",
  "course_area_percentage": 5
}, {
  "hard_skill": "Innovation",
  "course_area_percentage": 2
}, {
  "hard_skill": "International",
  "course_area_percentage": 5
}, {
  "hard_skill": "Marketing",
  "course_area_percentage": 7
}, {
  "hard_skill": "Operations",
  "course_area_percentage": 14
}, {
  "hard_skill": "Others",
  "course_area_percentage": 11
}, {
  "hard_skill": "Project",
  "course_area_percentage": 11
}]
var width = 500,
  height = 500,
  radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;


var color = d3.scale.quantize()
 .domain(d3.extent(pie_data, d=>d.course_area_percentage))
 .range(["#d7191c", "#f19d00", "#eef200", "#3fe256", "#008e15"]);

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
  .outerRadius(radius - 10)
  .innerRadius(0);

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
  .sort(null)
  .value(function(d) {
    return d.course_area_percentage;
  });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
  .data(pie(pie_data))
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "arc");

g.append("path")
  .attr("d", arc)
 .style("stroke", "gray")
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return color(d.data.course_area_percentage);
  });

g.append("text")
.attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
  })
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.data.hard_skill;
  });

function type(d) {
  d.population = +d.population;
  return d;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The first solution you present seems the adequate for this case. In your second solution the color interpolation makes different values have the same color, which in my case is not perfect. I need to show all the differences between the areas. The first linear scale does the trick.

Comment: That's exactly the difference between a linear scale and a quantize/quantile scale. The quantize/quantile scale will use **only** the colours in the range. So, if the range has only 5 colours, you'll get 5 colours in the chart. The linear scale, on the other hand, will create several different colours between the min/max values.